# Audio delay cycling through JavaScript object array?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, audio, delay

This is my website hosted by netlify all is good except when I try to cycle through this array of objects I get an initial lag in my audio the code that plays the audio is `"audio.play()"` of .5-2 sec.

And after I have cycled through them once the lag almost all completely disappears is this a netlify thing?

On my localhost is works like in the movies so perfect!

Would love to get a helpful link/video/advice, thanks.

https://csgo-weapons.netlify.app/

Comment: Because there is a thing called downloading and it takes awhile.... If you do not want a delay, you need to look at a way to preload the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a Netlify thing in particular, just an internet thing in general.

File loading isn't instantaneous on the web. When someone requests a file (in this case, the gun sound), it needs to get from the server to the client, and that takes some time (depending on things like network speeds, physical distance, etc.). On your local machine, these loading times are negligible, since the files are not traveling over the web.

After a file is loaded it's cached in the browser, which is why you're noticing no delay after cycling through all the guns.

A method to mitigate this issue would be to request and load *all* the sound files before the user starts cycling through all of the guns. That way, they don't need to be requested one-at-a-time on-demand. You could also try to reduce filesizes, although that won't help as much as the preloading.